# How to create fingerprint scanner software in java

Tags: fingerprint

What all things require for creating fingerPrint scanner application in java. what all SDKs require to built it and how to integrate it with application.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it, but here:

> L3TK is a Java-based software toolkit for analysis of Level 3
>   fingerprint features in high resolution fingerprint images. Level 3
>   fingerprint features are the sweat pores, ridge contours, and
>   edgeoscopic points along the contours.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/level3tk/